# Calling a function within a callback function of a callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm quite new to javascript coding so I'm trying to wrap my head around callback functions. I think I'm close but keep hitting a roadblock.

I'm using jquery to post to a REST api and I need to call one function and then another and another in sequence. From looking up answers I've found I need to use callback functions.

I'm using the below script in my function but it keeps stopping at the first callback so I know I'm missing something but after testing loads I just can't figure out what. Could anyone help shed some light as to where I'm going wrong please?

**Edited code based on feedback**

```
this.placeNewOrder = function(){
  if(items.length ==0){
    alert("it was 0");
    this.addToOrder();
    newOrder(username, password, Id,function(){postOrder(username, password, Id, currentId);});
  }
}

this.newOrder = function(username, password, Id, callback){
  //some code
  var username = username;
  var password = password;
  var Id = resultOfSomeCalculation;

  callback(username,password,result,this.currentId);
  alert("callback2 called");
};

this.postOrder = function(username, password, Id, currentId){
  //some code
  alert("finished");
};
```

Comment: Avoid  callback hell: use promises. :)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding callbacks. You use them when you have an asynchronous function and depend on results from that function. You're supposed to be passing to the callback whatever resource that needs to be treated in the callback.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, I think maybe I've got it now(fingers crossed!). So bearing that in mind I've edited the code above, does that look like I using them right now?

Comment: If you're not doing anything asynchronous (and your example code doesn't show that), don't use callbacks at all

Comment: Well this is only a snippet of the code that I've used, essentially I make one $post to a web table to obtain an ID, then use this ID to $post subsequent items to a different table. But each time I call the two functions in order from another function the second $post attempts first before the ID can be obtained, hence why I thought callbacks were the way to go here. If not do you have any suggestions how I can make the second function wait for the first to return?

Comment: Also again thanks for the help, i'm a total noob when it comes to javascript so learning as I go and feeling my way out!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript promises were introduced for this use case.

> A
>   [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
>   is a proxy for a value not necessarily known when the promise is
>   created. It allows you to associate handlers with an asynchronous
>   action's eventual success value or failure reason. This lets
>   asynchronous methods return values like synchronous methods: instead
>   of immediately returning the final value, the asynchronous method
>   returns a promise to supply the value at some point in the future.
>
> A Promise is in one of these states:
>
> - pending: initial state, not fulfilled or rejected.
> - fulfilled: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
> - rejected: meaning that the operation failed.